How to add a Discount input in Cart page on Shopify (Allow for Discount combinations)
By default, there is no discount input field on the cart page.
I attempted to add a custom input form with the action set to "/discount/YOUR_CODE". However, when I try to apply two different discount codes, the second code replaces the first one. Shopify allows for discount combinations, so this experience is not ideal.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After investigating, I found that we can achieve this by using the URL format "/checkout?discount=CODE1,CODE2,CODE3". Here are the steps with sample code:

Add a new template named cart-discount.liquid in the snippets/ folder with the following code:



<style>
  .cart_discounts {
    column-gap: 7px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    row-gap: 7px;
  }
  .cart_discounts li {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
  }
  .cart_discounts span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .cart_discounts .remove-discount {
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    height: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 9px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 10px;
  }
  .cart_discounts .remove-discount:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3;
  }
  .custom-discount-form {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
  }
  .custom-discount-form input {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .custom-discount-form input:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
  }
  .custom-discount-form .form {
    display: flex;
    gap: 7px;
  }
  .custom-discount-form .error {
    color: red;
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="cart_discounts-block" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 80vw">
  {% assign discount_codes = "" %}
  {% assign discount_list = "" %}
  {% for discount_application in cart.cart_level_discount_applications %}
    {% if discount_application.type == "discount_code" %}
      {% assign discount_codes = discount_codes | append: ',' | append: discount_application.title %}
    {% endif %}
    {% assign discount_list = discount_list | append: ',' | append: discount_application.title %}
  {% endfor %}
  
  {% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.line_level_discount_allocations.size %}
      {% for line_discount in item.line_level_discount_allocations %}        
        {% if line_discount.discount_application.type == "discount_code" %}
          {% assign discount_codes = discount_codes | append: ',' | append: line_discount.discount_application.title %}
        {% endif %}
        {% assign discount_list = discount_list | append: ',' | append: line_discount.discount_application.title %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  
  {% assign discount_codes = discount_codes | remove_first: ',' | split: ',' | uniq | join: ',' %}
  {% assign discount_list = discount_list | remove_first: ',' | split: ',' | uniq | join: ',' %}

  <div class="custom-discount-form">
    <div class="form">      
      <input name="custom-discount-input" type="text" />
      <button class="submit-discount button">Apply</button>
    </div>    
    <p class="error">Enter a valid discount code or gift card</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="cart_discounts list-unstyled" role="list" aria-label="{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}">
    {% assign codes = discount_list | split: ',' %}
    {% for code in codes %}
      {% if discount_codes contains code %}
        <li class="discounts__discount discounts__discount--position">
          {%- render 'icon-discount' -%}
          <span>{{ code | escape }}</span>
          <span class="remove-discount" data-code="{{ code }}">
            {%- render 'icon-close' -%}
          </span>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="discounts__discount discounts__discount--position">
          {%- render 'icon-discount' -%}
          <span>{{ code | escape }}</span>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  let enteredDiscountCode = '';
  function reloadCart() {
    const targetUrl = '/cart.js';
    fetch(targetUrl, {method: 'GET'}).then(res => {
      return res.json();
    }).then(data => {
      const appliedDiscounts = [];
      console.log(data);
      data.cart_level_discount_applications.forEach((discount) => {
        if(discount.type === 'discount_code') {
          appliedDiscounts.push(discount.title);
        }
      });
      data.items.forEach((item) => {
        item.line_level_discount_allocations.forEach((discount) => {
          if(discount.discount_application.type === 'discount_code') {
            appliedDiscounts.push(discount.discount_application.title);
          }
        });
      });
      console.log(appliedDiscounts);

      if (appliedDiscounts.indexOf(enteredDiscountCode) === -1) {
        const errorElement = document.querySelector('.custom-discount-form p.error');
        errorElement.style.display = 'block';
        errorElement.textContent = 'Enter a valid discount code or gift card';
      } else {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.submit-discount').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const discountcodes = '{{ discount_codes }}'.split(',') ? '{{ discount_codes }}'.split(',') : [];
    const discountCode = document.querySelector('.custom-discount-form input').value.trim();
    document.querySelector('.custom-discount-form p.error').style.display = "none";
    if (discountCode && discountCode.length) {
      if (discountcodes.indexOf(discountCode) === -1) {
        discountcodes.push(discountCode);
        enteredDiscountCode = discountCode;
        const targetUrl = '/checkout?discount=' + discountcodes.join(',');
        fetch(targetUrl, {method: 'GET'}).finally(() => {
          reloadCart();
        });
      } else {
        const errorElement = document.querySelector('.custom-discount-form p.error');
        errorElement.style.display = 'block';
        errorElement.textContent = 'Entered Coupon was applied';
      }      
    } else {
        const errorElement = document.querySelector('.custom-discount-form p.error');
        errorElement.style.display = 'block';
        errorElement.textContent = 'Enter a valid discount code or gift card';
    }
  });

  const codeTags = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-discount');
  codeTags.forEach(function(codeTag) {
    codeTag.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const discountcodes = '{{ discount_codes }}'.split(',') ? '{{ discount_codes }}'.split(',') : [];
      const discountCode = this.dataset.code;

      const remainCodes = discountcodes.filter(function(code) { return code !== discountCode });
      const targetUrl = '/checkout?discount=' + remainCodes.join(',');
      fetch(targetUrl, {method: 'GET'}).finally(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    });
  });
</script>




Open file sections/main-cart-footer.liquid and add {% render 'cart-discount' %} under div class="cart__blocks"


And this is the result:

Note: My code currently only applies for discounts of products and collections; it does not apply for discounts of shipping yet. You can try to add more logic later.

To add a discount input field to your Shopify cart page and allow for discount combinations, you need to:
Add a Discount Code Input in the Cart Template
Go to your theme code (Online Store > Themes > Actions > Edit Code), and find the cart.liquid file under the Sections or Templates folder (depending on your theme). You can add the following code where you want the discount field to appear.
Enable Discount Combinations (Manual and Automatic)
By default, Shopify doesn't allow stacking multiple discounts (manual or automatic). However, to enable this functionality, you would need an app like KartDiscount, which not only allows setting up a discount field on both the cart and product pages but also supports stacking multiple discounts.
KartDiscount helps you:
Add discount fields directly on your cart page and product pages.
Stack multiple manual and automatic discounts, ensuring your customers get the best offers.
You can configure these settings in the app and customize how you want to apply discounts.
Customize the User Experience
After setting up the discount functionality with your theme and KartDiscount, you may want to style the input field and button for a better user experience. You can do this by adding CSS to your theme files.
Disclosure: I work for KartDiscount, the app mentioned above.
<form action="/cart" method="post">
<input type="text" name="discount" placeholder="Enter discount code" />
<button type="submit">Apply Discount</button>

Make sure to adjust the code based on your theme structure, and using an app like KartDiscount can streamline the process and allow for more advanced discount features, such as stacking discounts.
